# How to get Vuejs links to switch between components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

To simplify the demo I'm using fake/pointless API)
I have the routers

```
const routes = [ 
  { path: '/',  component: Menu}, 
  {path: '/books', component: Index,
    props: route => ({ api:  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` })
  },
  {path: '/videos',component: Index,
    props: route => ({ api:  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos` })
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({ routes })
const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

The Menu component

```
var Menu = Vue.component('Menu', {
    template: `<ul> 
    <li><router-link to="/">home</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'videos'}">videos</router-link></li>
    <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'books'}">books</router-link></li>
    </ul>`})
```

**This is the problem, it does not switch from videos to books.**

Finally the **Index** component

```
var BookComponent = {
      props: {
        api: { type: String }
      },
    data: function () {
      return {
        items: null, 
      }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        this.getItems()
    },
    methods: {
        async getItems() {
            fetch(this.api).then(res => res.json())
            .then(res =>{ 
                this.items = res;
                this.loading = false
            })
        }, 
    },
    template: `
    <div class="home">
        <p v-for="post in items" :key="post.id">{{post.title}}</p>
    </div>
    `
} 
var Home = Vue.component('Home', BookComponent) 

var Index = {
  props: {
    api: {type: String,},
    filterBy: {type: String},
  },
  template: `
    <div>   
        <Menu />
        <div class="mainApp"  style="margin-top: 40px!important">
            <Home :api=api />
        </div>
     </div>`,
  component: { Menu, Home },
};
```

It doesn't work on jsfiddle but here's the code anyway [jsfiddle](https://jsbin.com/nubapupevu/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling named routes but you haven't defined any name in your routes so either use the path

```
  <li><router-link to="/videos">videos</router-link></li>
  <li><router-link to="/books">books</router-link></li>
```

or name your routes

```
const routes = [ 
  { path: '/',  component: Menu}, 
  {path: '/books', component: Index, name: 'books',
    props: route => ({ api:  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` })
  },
  {path: '/videos',component: Index, name: 'videos',
    props: route => ({ api:  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos` })
  }
]
```

Comment: It did not change anything!

Comment: Could you check the href value of the generated <a> link ?

Comment: I just tried to display the `{{api}}` just to see if it changes, and that works! So thee must me a problem ob `mounted`. that doesn't log anything on URL change

Answer (score 0):

1. To fix navigation - replace objects in `router-link` attribute `to` with `to='/videos'` and `to='/books'`
2. To fix render error, add `v-if` to post items loop, like this:

```
    <div class="home">
        <p v-if="items" v-for="post in items" :key="post.id">{{post.title}}</p>
    </div>
```

Here is [official docs for vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I just needed to  watch for the route changes and trigger the fetch method again.

```
    watch: {
        // call again the method if the route changes
        '$route': 'getItems'
    }
```